# PHP JAVA Bridge

Tags: linux, centos, php-java-bridge

I am very new to Linux but I am trying best to learn. We have dedicated hosting server of CentOS 6. It is configure with Apache Server as our public website. Now we need to install PHP JAVA Bridge on it.

What I did is, I install TomCat 6 and jdk 1.6. Then I copy JavaBridge.war file to $CATALINA_HOME/webapps folder and jar files on $CATALINA_HOME/lib folder. When I check from tomcat 8080 port JavaBridge is working very good.

Then I make symlink of $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/JavaBridge on my apache server. Untill here everything is okay

But when I try to browse from browser like http://www.xxx.com/JavaBridge I will get following error

### You don't have permission to access /JavaBridge/ on this server.

Apache Server at www.gizeleonline.com Port 80

Now my question is that do I am doing it in wrong way or do I have to get rid of Apache server or I am missing something.

Kindly help on this experts :)

Comment: Does the folder (JavaBridge) have read privs?

Comment: There's other issues on this site: Notice: Undefined variable: addstuff_code in /var/www/vhosts/gizeleonline.com/httpdocs/modules/addstuff/addstuff.php on line 147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was my mistake. I just re-image my server and re-install everything it start working everything. thanx for help every body